# Objective-C: Parse .m3u file to get .mp3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, mp3, m3u

I'm trying to stream audio in .m3u and would like to get the .mp3 components of the file. How would I go about parsing the .m3u?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can get nothing but filename from m3u file. Try opening it using any conventional text editor to see it.